# Get out of the planet without fuel propulsion

Tags: space, flight

Can electricity be used to propel aircraft out of the atmosphere and into space? If not, what other other options are there to get heavy stuff away from the planet?

Why the question? Fuel is limited and requires fuel tanks, and heavy fuel tanks that take too much space.

Electricity is not so limited. An area the size of Rome covered entirely in solar panels is enough to power almost the entire European continent, so I thought, why can't it power something to fly off the planet?

Comment: Try changing the planet, a very small planet with very tall mountains, just walk to the top, climb into the electrically charged slingshot & flick the switch.

Comment: "an area the size of Rome covered entirely in solar panels is enough to power almost the entire European continent" is a bit misleading. it's off by a factor of about 12 for actual solar panels operating on an actual planet, with its attendant little issues like: the sun hiding at night, rome not being on the equator under cloudless skies, etc.

Comment: You should check the wikipedia article on non rocket spacelaunch, and go to the sources in all of the footnotes.  Some of those hypothetical  non rocket space launch systems could be powered by electricity.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-rocket_spacelaunch

Comment: @PcMan thanks for the correction, then the solution is to make a bigger rome and move it south.

Comment: @thegoodguy and make it 12 times as big :) ... Your basic question premise is quite sound, but including lowgrade data like this degrades it a bit. (likely gotten from a solar-cell company, the figure is actually accurate is one assumes Rome is in perpetual, equatorial sunlight, and is covered by ultra-cutting-edge-lab-grade research solar panels). It requires an affective 460w/m2, whereas normal solar gives about 125w, for 1/8th of the time due to sun angle(night), clouds, etc)

Answer (score 9):

**Railguns!**

[image: railgun launch]
https://www.universetoday.com/73536/nasa-considering-rail-gun-launch-system-to-the-stars/

Railguns are electric.  They are appropriately sited in places where giant fields of solar panels might be.  And railguns are old tech!  The above image is from 2010!

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35139/what-is-the-possibility-of-a-railgun-assisted-orbital-launch

> Why would you want to do this? You just need to maintain the power
> systems and the rails, which are on the ground so you can have crews
> on it the whole time. The entire thing is reusable, and can be reused
> many times a day. You can also just have a standard size of object it
> launches and it opens a massive market of spacecraft producers, small
> companies that can't pay 20 million for a launch can now afford the
> 500,000 for a launch. The electric costs of a railgun launch drops to
> about 3$/kg, which means all the money from the launch goes to
> maintenance and capital costs and once the gun is paid down prices can
> drop dramatically. It is the only way that humanity has the tech for
> that can launch large quantities of object and in the end it is all
> about mass launched.

The fine answer on physics stack goes on to sidestep the problem of passenger-crushing acceleration by positing very long railguns and slower accelerations.  Other issues like atmospheric drag (take rail up side of mountain) and angle to achieve orbit can be addressed with non-weird engineering fixes.

Railguns!

Comment: I love how in the 19th century Vernes predicted people would be actually **shot** into space, then the idea was ridicularized in the 20th century, but now in the 21st century we are set to totally do that.

Comment: Verne did not predict, he wrote a story about hypothetical technology. .Verne's cannon was so short that the acceleration would be many, many times the g force that humans could survive, and Verne probably calculated that when writing the story but ignored it.  I suspect that a lot of readers also knew that as early as whenit was published.   A railgun mght be a "gun", but a railgun with acceleration low enough for human passengers to survive would accerate over many, many times the length of Verne's cannon, which was only a thousnd feet tall if I remember right.

Comment: @The Square-Cube Law  Just like the word 'ridicularize;'. What was old is now new again.

Comment: Now, put the railgun on a mountain, but also use hyperloop technology and the inside of the tube is at lower atmospheric density, with air locks along the way, but at the top of the mountain it enters into the atmospheric density at that level. The 'bullet' capsule does not need to accelerate to escape velocity until it comes close to the top of the mountain. The OP made no mention of costs, so building it is within the scope of the question..

Comment: Problem with railguns is that you need looooong rails to get anything living out of the gravity well, since if you go too fast, the living thing inside gets turned to paste from the acceleration.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: He realized the problem, discussed at some length, and handwaved it away with a techno-babblish water-based dampener.

Comment: [Further reading](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41135/what-are-the-biggest-challenges-for-high-altitude-rail-gun-launch-systems). It's an interesting thought but there's a mountain (more like several mountains) of technical problems to solve first, and even then there's no guarantee it will be more suitable than rocketry.

Comment: I don't believe this is feasible in atmosphere.  If your launcher is in atmosphere you have some horrendous shockwaves hitting the launcher.  If your launcher is in vacuum how do you get your spacecraft into atmosphere?  And your passage through the atmosphere is going to be spectacular--far more so than normal re-entry.  You need something very big and very long to get through at all.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you do NOT need to reach 'escape velocity' through reaction mass to get beyond the atmosphere. [Space elevators](https://www.isec.org/) do the trick perfectly. A slow and steady pull on a cable. The inertia/momentum of the platform itself provides the energy to accelerate the elevator cabin to the orbital velocity of the platform through the cable.

However, once you get out beyond the Earth's atmosphere, getting the delta-v to go FURTHER AWAY is the problem. However, you are so far up, the additional delta-v to reach escape velocity is far less than on the surface. Now it becomes feasible to apply the necessary additional delta-v through some mechanical process. Springs, for instance, or a pneumatic launch sled powered by electric compressors. Even steam from electrically-heated water would do the trick.

The catch-22 is, as you send every payload up to the platform and give it more delta-v to go into space, the platform itself loses velocity as it transfers the energy to the payload going up the cable.

Somehow, one needs to give the platform itself a continuous delta-v. So, on the platform, use an electric rail gun that keeps shooting heavy slugs at a tangent to the orbit of the platform. But wait, these slugs have to get to the platform (a process much like pulling yourself up by the bootstraps). So instead of bringing them up from Earth, bring the material (and water for the steam catapults?) in from asteroids.

So what propulsion system do you use to get the material through space? A very slow transportation system using ion engines. A slow-but-steady just-in-time continuous delivery schedule isn't concerned about how long it takes for delivery, just that the delivery is constant.

How do you get the platform up there in the first place?

Now we get to Willk's rail guns, modified by my comment about hyperloop technology going up a mountainside. A very high mountain. If the payload is not g-force sensitive, then the payload can accelerate quickly in a shorter launch tube. You might even want to continue to use this system to get supplies up to the platform. The elevator would be limited in cargo capacity, unless it was a HUGE cabin, and that would entail a very strong but very light cable.

For maneuvering around the platform, high-pressure electrically heated steam jets would work, using water as the reaction mass.

Of course, all of this assumes a very open-ended budget.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129086/discussion-on-answer-by-justin-thyme-the-second-get-out-of-the-planet-without-fu).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is possible. The reason it is not done is that it would be very awkward.

To get "out" of Earth you need to reach its escape velocity, which is around 11km/s (~7 miles per second) at sea level. It is smaller at [low Earth orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit) (LEO), but not much. Getting to that speed inside the atmosphere tends to start a fireball around you due to all the air friction. That is why asteroids fall to Earth flaming - they enter the upper atmosphere at speeds equal to or greater than escape velocity.

Everything we send away from Earth first gradually gets out of the atmosphere before going bat out of hell in space. But in space you can't fly like a plane - you need to throw some mass backward for [Newton's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton%27s_third_law) to push you forward. That's what the fuel is for.

Without fuel, you will either have to rely on solar sails - which is terribly inefficient with current technology, unless your whole payload is the sail itself - or... [you could push stuff with lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_propulsion). This is still mainly the stuff of science fiction, but it might be the way we send interstellar probes in the near future. The wiki in the link lists many forms of laser pushing.

In your case, for no actual fuel to be used, you are probably thinking of a laser-pushed [light sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail). Since photons have momentum, they can push stuff. It requires an absurd amount of power though, and if the laser is ground-based you have the problem of an atmosphere in the way. Also the Earth rotates, so unless you have an array of big space laser cannons around the planet, you can't push continuously.

Comment: You omit a number of other hypothetical launch systems, some of which could possibly be electric powered..   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-rocket_spacelaunch

Comment: @M.A.Golding I didn't remember some and didn't know about most of those. Thanks for the link, I love this kind of stuff!

Comment: "Asteroids" or "meteorites"?

Comment: @jub0bs why not both?

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw I believe _meteorites_ is the generic term for objects falling to Earth, be they asteroids or not.

Comment: @jub0bs OIC. Well, not all meteorites are incoming at escape speed then, but all asteroids are, so I think asteroids is more appropriate.